In PyBullet, the soft body and rigid body do not attach properly
In PyBullet, I'm trying to attach a soft body to a rigid body using p.createConstraint(), but it's not working properly. I referred to the following code: https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/examples/reduced_deformable_cube.py
import pybullet as p
from time import sleep
import pybullet_data

physicsClient = p.connect(p.GUI)

p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())

p.resetSimulation(p.RESET_USE_REDUCED_DEFORMABLE_WORLD)
p.resetDebugVisualizerCamera(4,-40,-30,[0, 0, 0])
p.setGravity(0, 0, -10)

tex = p.loadTexture("uvmap.png")
planeId = p.loadURDF("plane.urdf", [0,0,-2])

boxId = p.loadURDF("cube.urdf", [1,2,1],useMaximalCoordinates = True)

cube = p.loadURDF("reduced_cube/reduced_cube.urdf", [1,1,1])
p.changeVisualShape(cube, -1, rgbaColor=[1,1,1,1], textureUniqueId=tex, flags=0)
p.setPhysicsEngineParameter(sparseSdfVoxelSize=0.25)
p.setRealTimeSimulation(0)

p.createConstraint(parentBodyUniqueId= cube, parentLinkIndex=-1, childBodyUniqueId = 
boxId, childLinkIndex = -1, jointType = p.JOINT_FIXED, jointAxis=(0, 0, 0),
                    parentFramePosition=(1, 0.0, 0.0), childFramePosition=(1, 0.0, 0.0))

while p.isConnected():
  p.stepSimulation()
  p.getCameraImage(320,200)
  p.setGravity(0,0,-10)

Error message is below.
File "/home/ericlab/デスクトップ/sato/bullet3/examples/pybullet/examples/reduced_deformable_cube.py", line 27, in <module>
    p.createConstraint(parentBodyUniqueId= cube, parentLinkIndex=-1, childBodyUniqueId = boxId, childLinkIndex = -1, jointType = p.JOINT_FIXED, jointAxis=(0, 0, 0),
pybullet.error: createConstraint failed.

